# Update a component in parent window from a dialog of PrimeFaces Dialog Framework

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I am using PF dialog framework to open a dialog.

```
public void addSpecFeatures(){
    genericFeatures = new GenericFeatures();
    Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("widgetVar", "featureDialog");
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("PAGEName", options, null);
}
```

From the dialog I would like to update a component in the parent page. So, I tried below code

```
public void addFeatures(){
    if (null != genericFeatures && null != genericFeatures.getName()) {
        if (!genericFeaturesList.contains(genericFeatures)) {
            genericFeaturesList.add(genericFeatures);
            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.update("contentform:tabView:featureTable");
            context.closeDialog("PAGEName");
        }
    }
}
```

But code throws below exception:

> Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException:
>   org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find
>   component for expression "contentform:tabView:featureTable" referenced
>   from "j_id1".

While in parent Window I am able update messages with below code

```
<p:commandLink id="create" update=":contentform:tabView:message" />
```

If we are using PF Dialog Framework and open it through Java code, does it mean that there is no Parent-Child relation with the opener window?

Comment: Correct, the dialog framework uses an `iframe` to display what for jsf is a completely different view. So updating like you tried does not work. I thought of posting this as an answer since it is the valid one according to your actual question, but I leave it open since maybe others can try to think of a workaround for you (maybe something with storing the id in a shared scoped bean (session scoped?) and calling a javascript function in the parent document which calls a method on the server from the parent view which *can* update what you initially wanted to update from the dialog framework.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for reply..But its a weird implementation by PF team. i used ZK framework its also a component framework there its very easy to update Parent WIndow from the Modal Window . As PF team implement it  will not help to anyone to do some operation through dialog framework and then update backend page.

Comment: No it is not weird. In PrimeFaces it is very simple to update something in the parent window from a normal modal dialog. The dialog framwork provides (some) additional functionality that is not easy to do with a normal dialog (e.g. provide the dialogs with their own beans and scope). If you do not require this functionality, use normal dialogs. You can still put these in includes to prevent duplication and updating works then. So I think you choose the dialog framework for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With PrimeFaces Dialog Framework, dialogs are loaded as separate views in a HTML `<iframe>`.

In other words, the dialog has its own JSF component tree as well as its own HTML DOM tree which is independent from the page which opened the dialog. This is particularly useful for idempotent, bookmarkable and navigable dialogs.

However, your dialog appears to be not such one. It seems to still be  interested in its opener and be dependent from it during the close. The solution is relatively simple: just don't let the dialog be interested in its opener. Let the opener itself be interested in the dialog close event which is available as `dialogReturn` event in `<p:ajax>` nested in the dialog opener button. See also [Dialog Framework - Data showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/data.xhtml).

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton ... action="#{bean.showDialog}">
        <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update=":foo:bar" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

The alternative is to use a normal `<p:dialog>` instead of PF Dialog Framework.

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton ... oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" />
</h:form>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dialog">
    <h:form>
        ...
        <p:commandButton ... update=":foo:bar" oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide()" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I would have never thought (nor looked in the docs :-( ) for the  "don't-call-us-we'll-call-you" solution.

Comment: @Balusc Thanks for your detail answer but even after adding this above you said              `<p:ajax event="dialogReturn"  update=":contentform:tabView:featureTable"/>` this update not worked

Comment: It works for me. Your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. To start, try elaborating "not worked" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Press F12 in browser and track HTTP traffic and/or put a debug breakpoint at a strategic location, etc.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry its my mistake in `application-context.xml` file i added `scope=request` for bean .

Comment: @BalusC It is possible without closing popup we can update DatList?